# Vue 3 Composition API broken after re-rendering the component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

thanks for reading my post.

It's hard to describe my issue.

I have a reactive object cached globally(like a store and let's call it 'store' here) to preserve the states together with some actions. It's working all good initially. But when I added more pages & switching between the pages, the components are broken after re-rendering. The components can still read correctly from the store and call the actions to update the store data and can console.log the 'fingerprint' to show it's the same store. But the updated data in store is no longer updated in the UI. I can console.log the data in store which looks all good, but the UI is frozen with the data since last unmounted.

I'm providing my component code below.

```
    <template>
  <div class="min-w-full relative" ref="container">
    <hi-transition slow>
      <center-box
        v-if="loading"
        class="absolute w-full h-full left-0 top-0 text-primary-light opacity-50"
      >
        <hi-spinner class="w-1/6 h-1/6" :stroke="2" />LOADING...
      </center-box>
      <div v-else-if="noResult">
        No Result
      </div>
      <hi-markable
        v-else
        class="w-full h-full divide-y divide-primary-lighter overflow-y-auto block"
        :search="searchValue"
      >
        <div
          v-for="item in displayItems"
          :key="item.id"
          class="hover:bg-primary-lightest transition-colors duration-500 flex items-center block"
          @click="selectItem(item)"
          :style="{
            'min-height': minItemHeight + 'px',
            height: itemHeight + 'px'
          }"
          :class="{ active: currentItem === item }"
        >
          <slot :item="item" />
        </div>
      </hi-markable>
    </hi-transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { inject, ref } from "vue";
import HiSpinner from "@/ui/HiSpinner";
import CenterBox from "@/ui/elements/CenterBox";
import HiTransition from "@/ui/HiTransition";
import HiMarkable from "@/ui/HiMarkable";
import { computed } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "HiDataList",
  components: { HiMarkable, HiTransition, CenterBox, HiSpinner },
  props: {
    storeToken: String,
    minItemHeight: [Number, String],
    autoItemsPerPage: Boolean
  },
  emits: ["select"],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    //this store is a reactive object cached somewhere
    const store = inject(props.storeToken);
    //to make sure it's the same store
    console.log("fingerprint", store.fingerprint);
    const { displayItems, currentItem, loading, searchValue, noResult } = store;

    const container = ref(null);
    const itemHeight = computed(() => {
      return props.autoItemsPerPage
        ? store.autoItemHeight.value
        : props.minItemHeight;
    });
    if (props.autoItemsPerPage) {
      store.autoItemsPerPage(container, props.minItemHeight);
    }
    function selectItem(item) {
      console.log(item);
      emit("select", item);
      store.setCurrentItem(item);
    }
    return {
      displayItems,
      selectItem,
      container,
      itemHeight,
      currentItem,
      loading,
      searchValue,
      noResult
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.active,
.active:hover {
  @apply bg-primary-lighter border-primary-light;
}
</style>
```

The listStore

```
import { computed, reactive, watch, toRefs } from "vue";
import { useElementSize } from "@vueuse/core";
import { watchProps } from "@/utils/reactiveHelpers";

function filter(item, filters) {
  const f = (key, filter) => {
    const itemVal = item[key];
    if (Array.isArray(itemVal)) return itemVal.indexOf(filter) >= 0;
    else return itemVal === filter;
  };
  for (let key in filters) {
    const filterVal = filters[key];
    if (Array.isArray(filterVal)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < filterVal.length; i++) {
        if (f(key, filterVal[i])) return true;
      }
    } else {
      return f(key, filterVal);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

const getTime = date => {
  if (date.milliseconds) return date.milliseconds;
  if (date.seconds) return date.seconds;
  if (date.getTime) return date.getTime();
};

const createListStore = (source, settings = {}) => {
  const state = reactive({
    source: source,
    currentPage: 0,
    itemsPerPage: 0, //zero means display all
    loading: true,
    ready: false,
    noData: false,
    noResult: false,
    filters: {},
    search: null,
    searchables: settings.searchables || [],
    sortBy: null,
    sortType: "alpha",
    desc: false,
    currentItem: null,
    autoItemHeight: 0,
    fingerprint: Math.random() * 10000000000000000
  });
  // const { itemsPerPage,source,filters,search,searchables,sortBy,sortType,desc } = toRefs(state);
  const {
    itemsPerPage,
    ready,
    loading,
    noResult,
    search,
    autoItemHeight
  } = toRefs(state);
  watchProps(state, "source", v => {
    if (typeof v !== "undefined") {
      state.ready = true;
      state.loading = false;
      if (!v.length) state.noData = true;
    }
  });
  const currentPage = computed(() => state.currentPage + 1);
  // const itemsPerPage = computed(() => state.itemsPerPage);

  const totalItems = computed(() => results.asc.length);

  const from = computed(() => {
    if (totalItems.value === 0) return 0;
    return state.currentPage * state.itemsPerPage + 1;
  });
  const to = computed(() => {
    const t = from.value + displayItems.value.length - 1;
    return t > totalItems.value ? totalItems.value : t;
  });
  const totalPages = computed(() => {
    if (totalItems.value === 0 || state.itemsPerPage === 0) return 1;
    return Math.ceil(totalItems.value / state.itemsPerPage);
  });
  const gotoPage = page => {
    console.log("gotoPage", page);
    state.currentPage = page - 1;
    console.log(state.currentPage);
  };
  const prevPage = () => {
    if (state.currentPage > 0) state.currentPage--;
  };
  const nextPage = () => {
    if (state.currentPage < totalPages.value) state.currentPage++;
  };

  const updateFilters = (filter, val) => {
    state.filters[filter] = val;
  };

  /**
   *
   * @param column
   * @param desc
   * @param type "alpha"|"number"|"date"|"time"
   */
  const sortBy = (column, desc = false, type = "alpha") => {
    state.sortBy = column;
    state.desc = desc;
    state.sortType = type;
  };

  function doSearch(item) {
    const searchables = state.searchables;
    for (let i = 0; i < searchables.length; i++) {
      const key = searchables[i];
      let value = item[key];
      if (value && typeof value === "string") {
        value = value.toLowerCase();
      }
      if (value && value.indexOf(state.search) >= 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  const results = reactive({
    desc: [],
    asc: []
  });
  function calcResults() {
    if (!state.ready || state.noData) return null;
    // console.log("re-calc results....");
    const hasFilters = Object.keys(state.filters).length > 0;
    // console.log(Object.keys(state.filters));
    let items = [];
    if (hasFilters || (state.search && state.search.length)) {
      //do filter & search
      const source = state.source;
      for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        const item = source[i];
        // console.log(filter(item, state.filters));
        if (hasFilters && !filter(item, state.filters)) {
          continue;
        }
        if (state.search && state.search.length && !doSearch(item)) {
          continue;
        }
        items.push(item);
      }
      if (!items.length) {
        results.desc = results.asc = [];
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      items = state.source;
    }

    if (state.sortBy) {
      //do sort
      const sort = state.sortBy;
      // const desc = state.desc ? -1 : 1;
      const type = state.sortType.toLowerCase();
      items.sort((a, b) => {
        a = a[sort];
        b = b[sort];
        if (type === "date" || type === "time") {
          return getTime(a) - getTime(b);
        } else {
          if (typeof a === "string") a = a.trim();
          if (typeof b === "string") b = b.trim();
          if (state.sortType.toLowerCase() === "number") {
            return a - b;
          } else {
            return a.localeCompare(b, "en", { sensitivity: "base" });
          }
        }
      });
    }
    results.asc = items;
    results.desc = [...items].reverse();
    // return items;
  }
  //changed to watch for the wired vue error.
  watchProps(
    state,
    ["source", "filters", "search", "searchables", "sortBy", "sortType"],
    () => {
      calcResults();
      state.noResult = results.asc.length === 0;
    }
  );

  const displayItems = computed(() => {
    if (!results.asc.length) return [];
    const re = state.desc ? results.desc : results.asc;
    if (state.itemsPerPage === 0) return re;

    const from = state.currentPage * state.itemsPerPage;
    const to = from + state.itemsPerPage;
    return re.slice(from, to);
  });
  /**
   *
   * @param elementRef  ref
   * @param minHeight   Number
   * @param itemHeightRef ref
   */
  const autoItemsPerPage = (elementRef, minHeight) => {
    const { height } = useElementSize(elementRef);
    // console.log(elementRef);
    watch(height, v => {
      const items = Math.floor(v / minHeight);
      // itemHeightRef.value = v / items;
      // console.log(v / items);
      state.itemsPerPage = items;
      state.autoItemHeight = v / items;
    });
  };

  const setCurrentItem = item => {
    console.log("set current", state.fingerprint);
    state.currentItem = item;
  };

  const currentItem = computed(() => state.currentItem);

  return {
    currentPage,
    itemsPerPage,
    totalItems,
    displayItems,
    from,
    to,
    totalPages,
    gotoPage,
    prevPage,
    nextPage,
    ready,
    loading,
    updateFilters,
    sortBy,
    search: v => (state.search = v),
    searchValue: search,
    autoItemsPerPage,
    setCurrentItem,
    currentItem,
    noResult,
    autoItemHeight,
    fingerprint: state.fingerprint
  };
};
export { createListStore };
```

The store provider

```
import { provide } from "vue";
import { createListStore } from "@/ui/storeProvider/listStore";

const storeDepot = {};

export const provideListStore = (token, source, settings = {}) => {
  if (!storeDepot[token]) {
    console.log("create new store", token);
    storeDepot[token] = createListStore(source, settings);
  }
  provide(token, storeDepot[token]);
  return storeDepot[token];
};
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of the store itself? In order to get your DOM updated, you should have refs or ractive attribues on yout store, from this picture I can't say if they are/aren't

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for your comments. Please see the store updated in the post. It's not actually about the reactivity itself. The code is working all good during the initial mount. The strange behaviour is when mounted again, all component states remains as last mounted. Function calls but not changing any data/state.